# Why isn't the css selector :nth-child working properly?

Tags: html, css

I created a table and I was make a zebra stripped style starting with the 3rd row. But the `:nth-child` isn't working how i was wondering. Follow the code below:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

th,
td,
table {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 15px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.tr:nth-child(2n + 3) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <th colspan='2'>Grade de Disciplinas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <th>Horário</th>
      <th>Matéria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>13:00 - 13:50</td>
      <td>Matemática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>13:50 - 14:40</td>
      <td>Matemática</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>14:40 - 15:30</td>
      <td>Português</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>15:50 - 16:40</td>
      <td>Português</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>16:40 - 17:30</td>
      <td>Inglês</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='tr'>
      <td>17:30 - 18:20</td>
      <td>Inglês</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And that's the result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAHEs.png)

As you can see in the code above, I typed the equation `(2n + 3)` in the `nth-child`. I can't find what I typed wrong.

Comment: Could you please make the minimal reproducible example necessary to replicate this bug? (Unless the entire code is required to recreate the bug, in which case my bad)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the expected result?

Comment: `.tr:nth-child(2n + 2)` ?? or `tbody .tr:nth-child(2n + 2)` ? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwpVRmm

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since `<tr>` is an HTML element, you don't need an `.`, so your current selector:

```css
.tr:nth-child(2n + 3)
```

Wont work because `tr` isn't a class.

---

But since the `<thead>` also contains some `<tr>` I'd use a CSS selector which only targets `<tr>` inside the `<tbody>` like so:

```
tbody > tr:nth-child(2n + 3)
```

<sup>Note the missing `.`!</sup>

```css
body {
    font-family: monospace;
}

th, td, table {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
    width: 50vw;
    margin: auto;
}

td, th {
    padding: 15px 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

th {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

tbody > tr:nth-child(2n + 3) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <th colspan='2'>Grade de Disciplinas</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <th>Horário</th>
            <th>Matéria</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>13:00 - 13:50</td>
            <td>Matemática</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>13:50 - 14:40</td>
            <td>Matemática</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>14:40 - 15:30</td>
            <td>Português</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>15:50 - 16:40</td>
            <td>Português</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>16:40 - 17:30</td>
            <td>Inglês</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='tr'>
            <td>17:30 - 18:20</td>
            <td>Inglês</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```